# where is object stored in xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

Javascript:

```
var test_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
test_request.open("POST","/testupload",true);
test_request.send(image.sourceFile);
```

Node.js express:

```
app.post("/testupload", function(req, res){
    where is the image.sourceFile in req?
});
```

where is the image.sourceFile in req? req.body shows {}, how can I get the image?

Comment: take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

Comment: do you know how i can make changes and get the request that is sent from javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to the form data of a `POST` request, you should try to use `body-parser` middleware first.

```
const express        = require('express');
const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
const app            = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }));
```

now you can get form data in `req.body`;

Comment: Thank you so so so much!

Comment: Now I get this error: request entity too large. I am sending the whole image sourceFile. any suggestions?

Comment: @Pano please change the code like this. `app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
  app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'audio/wav', limit: '50mb' }));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: '50mb',
  }));`